# Using unsigned int vs. checking if negative

Tags: c++

Say I have a class with an integer that should be always positive with a simple C'tor:

```
class A {
    unsigned int x;
    public:
    A(unsigned int X) : x(X) {}
};
```

And lets say someone accidentally creates an A object with the value `-5`.
Of course, this is not valid and `X` will get a really huge value since the MSB now doesnt stand for the number sign.
Problem is, that now I can't really check if the number is negative or invalid (maybe bitwise?).

Should I just avoid the `unsigned` and just use a plain `int`? By doing so, i could just throw an exception if the given value is beyond a max value OR below zero.

Would love to hear some suggestions.

Comment: I always choose types according to their semantics. If `x` should only be non-negative - then use `unsigned`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe **but** keep in mind that this makes sense for _storing_ values. When doing arithmetic, be _very_ wary about mixed-sign calculations - they can be painfully surprising. Always compile `-Wall -pedantic` to catch these cases early

Comment: Using unsigned is rarely a good idea. It's never matching the variable semantic, because you still have to check for the maximum. The code is way more prone to bugs, and cluterred with casts.

Comment: At some point you have to assume the programmer using your class is a grown up person and can take responsibility for himself. If `x` needs to be in a particular range, a traditional bounds check will work well for either signed or unsigned types. If the user of `A` is reckless, he might just pass in a reasonable but completely wrong value to the constructor anyways (e.g. copying the value from somewhere else without checking).

Comment: Well, if the the user of `A` puts in a negative number into an `unsigned int`, then that's his problem. The interface clearly says that the number has to be `unsigned`, whatever conversion happens in the client code is not your responsibility. If the user puts in a `-5`, then you can assume he's aware of the language's workings and really wanted a `4294967291` or something similar in there and if that value is too large for your `A`, then this is the case you need to check, and if it isn't too large, then where's your problem?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Two approaches come to mind:

1. Add an explicit conversion for the 'signed' types.

   ```
   #include <cassert>

   class A {
       unsigned int x;
       public:
       A(unsigned int X) : x(X) {}
       explicit A(int X) : x(static_cast<unsigned>(X)) {
           assert(X>=0); // note X, not x!
       }
   };

   int main()
   {
       A ok(5);
       A bad(-5);
   }
   ```
2. Prohibit implicit conversions by deleting better overloads:

   ```
   A(int X) = delete;
   A(long X) = delete;
   A(char X) = delete;
   ```

   This will require all users to cast to unsigned *before* constructing the A instance. It's safe but clumsy.

Note that this does **not** prohibit implicit conversions from **all** integral types (e.g. `enum`s) so you'd need to do more to make this fool proof.

Here is a rudimentary SFINAE-based example that accepts all implicit conversions **except** if they involve signed values: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72ef5c7b19533eed)**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>

class A {
    unsigned int x;
    public:
    template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type>
    A(T X) : x(X)
    {
        static_assert(!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed, "Signed types cannot be accepted");
    }
};

int main()
{
    A ok(5u);
    A bad(-5);
}
```

Comment: Nice... the first way is new to C++11 right? (After you edited, the 2nd way :) )

Comment: @Rouki yes indeed. Also added a proper SFINAE based sample that takes into account any integral type.

Comment: Helped alot, thanks. Does the last method provide compile-time check for the negative value?

Comment: @Rouki yes, `static_assert` if fails breaks the compilation. In this specific case, it wll break if T is signed integer type

Comment: On the last solution, I'm going to quote Stroustrup: "An organisation that treats its programmers as morons will soon have programmers that are willing and able to act like morons only." By forcing the user of the class to always cast to unsigned, even the literal `0`, you'll soon end up with the class always being used with an explicit `(unsigned)somevalue` argument, and defeat the whole point.

Comment: @DanielKO I was merely pointing it out. Note how it's _not_ one of my 'designated' approaches :). Also, "defeat the whole point" is a fallacy, because it is obviously more noticeable that way. Besides, there is no need to cast the literal `0`, as you ***should*** just use the literal `0u` (like my example already showed!)

Comment: If the normal use case is where the origin of the data is an `int` value known to be non-negative, the pattern `A foo((unsigned)bar)` will pop up everywhere; the compile-time guarantees are useless now, as you forced the programmers to lie every time they have to use `A`. It makes the normal use case inconvenient, and you end up missing exceptional cases because of that.

Comment: @DanielKO I'd tend to say, A should probably just take an `int` if that's the _normal use case_. <whistle/>

Answer (score 7):

> And lets say someone accidentally creates an A object with the value -5

While it may be good practice to make your program robust enough to accept such errors, the root cause of the bug is a sloppy programmer who does not have sufficient warnings enabled.

To get to the bottom of the problem, you need to ensure that the code is compiled with all warnings enabled, and perhaps also consider using an external static analysis tool.

Answer (score 1):

I probably agree with *DanielKO* about `pattern will pop up everywhere`. And note that *sehe* SFINAE-based solution don't work for uint64 -> uint32 [truncation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9e779bde312efe2). So my answer:

```
class A {
 public:
  using value_type = unsigned int;

  template <class T>
  explicit A(T x): x_(boost::numeric_cast<value_type>(x)) { // can be check in debug only
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "T must be integral");
  }

 private:
  value_type x_;
};
```

And [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d493050830bae329).